# Request form URL encoded within a request

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I'm trying to make a request form_url_encoded when requesting a request, but it's giving me an error on the console that is already on port 3000, it's giving some error but not finding it, because if I leave the default as in the doc, it runs normal and opens at the door. I get:

> Error: connect ECONNREFUSED

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const axios = require("axios");
const qs = require("qs");

const requestBody = {
  refresh_token:
    "1000.51355b1f8f5a8176026525670b5bbf3e.93c56a6bd3cb4589bd65b334810848cf",
  client_id: "1000.KS2QNMSAQIMS74YBGZROSXD8QD3GWO",
  client_secret: "06abfcc05409c430fb15252d47e8d9fe03a3582cbc",
  rant_type: "refresh_token",
};

const config = {
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
  },
};

const config2 = {
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
};

axios
.post(
  "/crm7/sell_order",
  { test: "test" },
  config2
)
.then((res) => {
  console.log(res);
  return  axios.post("https://accounts.blue.com/oauth/v2/token", qs.stringify(requestBody), config);
})
.then((res) => {
   console.log(res)
})
.catch((err) => {
  console.log(err)
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: You may want to try https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch inside your post router.

Comment: tried it, but i need use the axios

Comment: What does it say in `console.log(res)` or in `console.log(err)`

Comment: nothing, return me error Error: connect ECONNREFUSED